# Blueimp/jQuery File Upload autoUpload fail when one of the selected files is not image

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

My acceptFileTypes option is standard `/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i`. The problem is, autoUpload fires correctly only if all the selected files are `gifs/jpgs/pngs`. The moment there's a file that isn't an image, autoUpload doesn't fire.

```
jqXHR = $('#button').fileupload({
    url: uploadURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: {
        'data': myData
    },
    autoUpload: true,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    singleFileUploads: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    disableImageResize: true,
    previewMaxWidth: 240,
    previewMaxHeight: 240,
    previewThumbnail: false,
    previewCanvas: true,
    previewCrop: true
})
.on('fileuploadadd', function(e, data) {
    //nothing here
})
.on('fileuploadprocessalways', function(e, data) {
    var index = data.index,
        file = data.files[index];
    if (file.error) {
        console.log(file.error);
    }
    else {
        var node = $('<li/>').addClass('node').prependTo($(data.context)),
            inner = $('<div/>').addClass('node-inner').appendTo(node),
            controls = $('<div/>').addClass('node-controls').appendTo(inner);
        if (file.preview) {
            inner.append(file.preview);
        }
        inner.append(nodeProgress.clone());
        controls.append(cancelBtn.clone(true).data(data));
    }
});
```

I'm open to all suggestions. Basically I want the user to select files, and once selected, it will start uploading. I tried setting `autoUpload` to `false` and do all the validation and error handling manually in `fileuploadadd`, but the problem is it throws all kinds of errors when I do a `data.files.splice(index, 1);`. I'm guessing it's because the array pointer gets messed up and the script is written to handle that. I also tried firing `data.submit()` manually everytime an image is selected, which was pretty dumb of me because then `data.submit()` gets fired as many times as there are images selected.